# Google sheets regexmatch for 2 consecutive characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this simple match in google app script that I'm trying to port over to google sheets. It just matches 2 consecutive letters with a space infront and a character in back.

`big customers coming back slower, moved to incumbents cc.`

this will work in GAS:

`var match_ar = sentence.match(/\s([a-z])\1\S/)`

I'm trying to get `regexmatch` to do the same thing

I've tried `regexmatch(B6,"\s(([:alpha:])\1)")`, `regexmatch(B6,"\s([:alpha:])\1")`

I'm getting an error `Error Function REGEXMATCH parameter 2 value "\s(([:alpha:])\1)" is not a valid regular expression.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex itself is more or less correct, although I would rewrite more simply as  `(\w)\1\S`, unless there's some reason you need nested capture groups.

Your real problem is that Google uses the RE2 regex engine, which, unlike PCRE, [doesn't support backreferences at all AFAICT](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt), so it's tripping up over the `\1` token at the end of the expression - remove it and `=REGEXMATCH(B6, " (\w)\S")` evalutates just fine. Unfortunately, that makes it impossible as far as I know to match double letters without explicitly writing out every possible combination in the regex, which is a lot uglier:

```
 (?:aa|bb|cc|dd|ee|ff|gg|hh|ii|jj|kk|ll|mm|nn|oo|pp|qq|rr|ss|tt|uu|vv|ww|xx|yy|zz)\S
```

Or, I mean, if it's only the string `" cc."` you're trying to match, and not all double-lettered combinations patterned like that:

```
 cc\.
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are unlikely to have a word like "aardvark" or "llama" or "oogenisis" in your string, the character after a *space-double-letter* combo seems moot. In other words, finding *space-double-letter* should find only the matches you want without going further.

That said, try this:

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(B6,JOIN("|"," "&REPT(CHAR(96+SEQUENCE(26)),2))))`

It is similar to what contributor "Arcaeca" offered, except that it builds out the long list of double-letter combos formulaically.

However, as "Arcaeca" noted, if you *only ever* need to find *exactly* `cc`, it's simple:

`=REGEXMATCH(B6," cc")`

(Again, any trailing period or other character is moot.)